# A way to access Last Updated Time on any XML record in FogBugz

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, xmlhttprequest, fogbugz, fogbugz-api

In my application I am accessing FOGBUGZ API in the form of XML to retrieve data. It is running fine. But Issue is that, we ever it start, it takes pull of whole data from starting point. Here I searched a lot on Internet, but i could not find any status log maintaining by FogBugz to check whether data is updated or not.

FogBugz URL ::

https://fogbugz.xxxx.in/api.asp?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&cmd=search&=project:=306+type3A%22case%22cols=ixPersonAssignedTo,sPersonAssignedTo,ixFixFor,sFixFor,hrsElapsed,ixProject,sProject,dtDue,ixBug,ixBugEvent,sTitle,ixProject,ixArea,ixFixFor,ixCategory,ixPersonAssignedTo,ixPriority,dtDue,hrsCurrEst,sVersion,ixMailbox,listIntervals

Example of XML CODE

```
<case ixBug="22547" operations="edit,assign,resolve,reactivate,close,email,remind">
  <ixPersonAssignedTo>3</ixPersonAssignedTo>
  <sPersonAssignedTo>Person One</sPersonAssignedTo>
  <ixFixFor>1797</ixFixFor>
  <sFixFor>XXX</sFixFor>
  <hrsElapsed>2.17582988739014</hrsElapsed>
  <ixProject>306</ixProject>
  <sProject>Project XXX</sProject>
  <dtDue/>
  <ixBug>22547</ixBug>
  <sTitle>MiniReview</sTitle>
  <ixArea>3383</ixArea>
  <ixCategory>2</ixCategory>
  <ixPriority>6</ixPriority>
  <hrsCurrEst>2</hrsCurrEst>
  <sVersion>TF201105</sVersion>
  <ixMailbox>0</ixMailbox>
</case>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if Case was updated, you can simply check `ixBugEventLatest` (don't forget to include it in `cols` list). This field increases whenever case is changed. For other lists (people, areas, ...) I don't think there is good way to see if they have been changed, other then downloading full lists again.

**Update:** another good source of "change" information is `dtLastUpdated` field, which contains date (UTC) of last change to the case.

Btw, you may have more luck getting good answer at http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanx for the reply. Here ixBugEventLatest gives some numeric value, it means this values increases when updation happen in this row. Is I am right ?

Comment: @Napster: ixBugEventLatest is a numeric value. It increases whenever there is a change to the Case (Bug). For example, when someone adds comment to the case, or changes case priority, or does any other change to the case, ixBugEventLatest is changed as well.

Comment: @Napster, btw, if you just need the date when case was last updated, you can also use `dtLastUpdated` field.